# How to update arguments in each iteration of scipy.optimize.newton

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, newtons-method

I am using newton to optimize a longish cost function that takes in multiple arguments performs some calculations and compares the original value of a variable 'a' to a new version. However, each time newton iterates through the function I would also like it to update the value of another variable that it is not optimizing which also factors in to the calculation.

Essentially:

```
def func(a, ap, etc..)
   perform calculations
   a_1 = function of (a,ap,etc)
   ap_1 = function of (a,ap,etc)
   return (a - a_1)
```

and then

```
root = newton(func, a, args = (ap, etc..))
```

I would like ap to update to the value of `ap_1` in each iteration of newton's Optimization.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to do this?

I've tried to use a single array `X = [a, ap]` but I don't want ap to be optimized just a. I have also tried making `ap` a global variable and updating it inside the function I've defined but that doesn't seem to update within the newton's Optimization function.

Comment: How are you changing ap_1 without "optimizing" it?  Or alternatively, how do you expect to optimize a function that has some independently varying parameter?  If an optimizer is expected to optimize f(x), then f(a) can't depend upon the iteration.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do multivariable optimization. Have you considered using one of SciPy's multivariable optimizers? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `for` `loop` to pass `scipy`'s `optimize.newton` function updated values of `b`, and we'll make half the values `None` so that it is not factored in for those iterations:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def f(x, a, b):
    if b is not None:
        b += b
    return x**3 - a + b if b is not None else 0

fder = lambda x, a, b: 3 * x**2
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.standard_normal(100)
a = np.arange(-50, 50)
b = 5
vec_res = [optimize.newton(f, _x, fprime=fder, args=(_a, _b), maxiter=200) for _x, _a, _b in zip(x, a, [b + __b if __b % 2 else None for __b in range(x.shape[0])])]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(a, vec_res, ls='-', lw=1.5, color=[1, 0, 0])
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]

Whereas if `b` is not factored in at all (i.e. `b = None`):

```
b = None
vec_res = optimize.newton(f, x, fprime=fder, args=(a, b), maxiter=200)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(a, vec_res, ls='-', lw=1.5, color=[1, 0, 0])
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]

And if `b` is not updated:

```
b = 5
vec_res = optimize.newton(f, x, fprime=fder, args=(a, b), maxiter=200)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(a, vec_res, ls='-', lw=1.5, color=[1, 0, 0])
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]